# JS Replacing Backslashes After Word

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace double backslashes "\\" within the given string after the word, **content**, with only a single backslash, \?

```
var a = "blah blah \\ \\ content:\"whiskey \\\\";
```

so that it shows up as:

```
var a = "blah blah \\ \\ content:\"whiskey \\";
```

I tried the following without success.

```
 a.replace(/content:*\\\\\"/g, "\\"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to tackle the entire problem with a regular expression, I'd just break the string on "content" and do replacement on right half.

```
function fn(x) { 
    var i = x.indexOf("content");
    return x.substr(0,i) + x.substr(i).replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");
}

// this evaluates true
fn("blah blah \\ \\ \\\\ content:\"whiskey \\\\\\\\ \\\\") ==
   "blah blah \\ \\ \\\\ content:\"whiskey \\\\ \\"
```

Comment: I think that this is the right answer. Unfortunately, regexes aren't always the solution. :(

Comment: Christopher, are you advocating splitting up the strings since it's simpler?

Comment: Splitting up the string is better because then you can do all the replacements at once.

Comment: @Kevin Yes. In my opinion, if it isn't obvious how to correctly apply a regex, then it usually just isn't the appropriate solution. The "content" and backslash pieces of your requirements seem to be somewhat orthogonal concerns, so it's more clear (and easier to make changes to later) if you deal with them in two distinct steps.

Answer (score 1):

```
a.replace(/(content:.*)\\\\/g, "$1\\");
```

Specifically of problem, you had a `"` in your regex, you need `.*` to match anything, and you need to put a group around the first part so you can retrieve it later.

You do need to run this multiple times until it has done all the replacements, unfortunately, because of the way that javascript does matching.

Comment: That's interesting that it must be run multiple times. What's a best practice for making sure you run it to make all replacements?

Comment: Absolutely no idea. You could just keep replacing until the string stops changing, or perhaps wait until the string length stops decreasing, for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this, without replace method!

```
a.split('\\\\').join('\\');
```

And the result shold be:

```
blah blah \ \ content:"whiskey \
```

Comment: That's... not what they wanted.

Comment: he say if he want to replace double backslashes into single backslash, so i give what i know for.

Comment: He says "within the given string **after the word 'content'**". Yours also does replacement before the word 'content'.

Comment: uh oh, well, my answer should :`var rpl = a.substring(a.search('content:'),a.length).split('\\\\').join('\\');alert(a.substr(0,a.search('content:'))+rpl);`

Comment: with all due respect, faid, that looks very complicated